# pip3 installation error - new ubuntu 18.04 installation

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, apt, dpkg

I'm rebuilding after a crash & subsequent upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Everything seems to be back to normal except for Python's pkg manager.

Below is launched by:

```
$sudo apt update
$sudo apt install python3-pip
```

The logs at first say that python3-pip is already installed:

```
python3-pip is already the newest version (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.1).
```

Then the installation apparently bombs as shown:

```
dpkg: error processing package libclojure-java (--configure):
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of librobert-hooke-clojure:
dpkg: error processing package librobert-hooke-clojure (--configure):
```

Also at the bottom of the error message:

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I understand dpkg is the Debian pkg manager but I am unsure of the best next step.

Comment: `sudo apt update --fix-missing`?

Comment: I'm voting to migrate this question to https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

do you try to missing package by this command

> sudo apt-get install -f

and then for update missing try

> sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

and for upgrade missing package

> sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing

Comment: the problem posted is a `dpkg` problem - not a `pip` problem.

Comment: After removing unused packages,

    $sudo apt install python3-pip

returns the following:

    python3-pip is already the newest version (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.1).

    $pip3 --version 

returns a 'pip._internal' ModuleNotFound error. Next idea?

Comment: please try for upgrade you pip via >> curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py ;; 
python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall

Comment: 19.3.1 now installed at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip. Thank you!